# deploying resource files from xcode

Tags: xcode, build-process

How does one copy resource files (config/data/image) files to an applictions home directory on the iPhone.

A related question [Loading Data Files on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317959/loading-data-files-on-iphone), received an answer "just add them to your project; Xcode will copy them to the .app bundle when it builds your application".

How does one do this? (If this is a simple question, a manual reference/page# is fine)

I want to be able to copy a file onto the iPhone simulator and open it at runtime. I have tried to do this by adding 'copy file' targets, although I havent been able to find the files at runtime.

I know using property list, or sql lite database is prefered over file io, but I would still like to understand how to achieve this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my app, I have a sql lite DB which I just dropped in the root of my project folder and added to the resources folder of my project, and it winds up in the bundle, accessible by the app.

http://img68.imageshack.us/img68/3047/xcoderesourceslw5.png

I assume this will work for any file. I didn't have to write any special targets or operations.

In your app, this file then shows up as follows:

```
NSString *dbFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                            pathForResource:@"dictionary" 
                            ofType:@"db"];
```

Comment: Thanks, I didnt really know anything about bundles, so I wasnt sure where the files where being copied to.

Answer (score 3):

I just found this site, [Bundle Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/CFBundles.html) it explains, how to access resources set in your project at runtime. I assume its just as easy to use single files.